# Calculate the access time without the support of any paging scheme?

Tags: x86, operating-system, paging

This is a question which was asked in our previous tests and I am not able to find the answer to it. 
**Problem 1:** You are writing a program which uses Intel’s IA32 memory paging scheme. Small Page size is 4KB and large page size is 4MB. Your program is given the entire logical address space 2^32. A page table is needed to translate the logical address to physical address.

**1.a** Assuming that a memory(access time is 100ns). CPU generates a logical address 0x00ffffff to access a physical memory(configured as 16MB*32). How long does it take to receive the data from memory without the support of the paging scheme ?

My Take on this question is-  the question is wrong as the question should tell how it wants me to decode the logical address. But I think I am wrong.

Comment: Seems really ambiguous.  You should ask whoever wrote it for clarification.  They might mean "without a TLB" (i.e. the CPU has to walk the page tables for every memory access).  They probably don't mean for a TLB hit (i.e. just 100ns + a couple cycles for the TLB), because that would be "without any *overhead* from paging", not "without *support*".  If it's a 2-byte or larger access, it's split across a 4k boundary (which in practice has a large penalty, ~100 cycles, on CPUs before Skylake, whether or not it's within a single hugepage.)

Comment: Possible but unlikely that they mean without hardware support *for* the paging scheme; i.e. the CPU traps to a software TLB miss handler which walks the page tables and fills the TLB entry before retrying the load or store that faulted.  But trapping on TLB misses is still hardware support.  Extremely unlikely (but does fit the wording) that they mean with paging disabled, so you always just walk the page table in software for every load/store.  e.g. a function that takes a virtual address as an arg, and returns the loaded data, using physical addresses for all real memory operands.